# Need to optimize for faster search in big folder

Tags: python, search, optimization

I have a folder that contain a lot of files and i need to optimize the speed of the search because i have over 1k of different files to search , actually i am using this :

```
for path,dirs,files in os.walk('M:/MYFOLDER'):
```

But it is taking really long time ( over 30 minutes ) to search in all the folder (because it search file by file), but the "Windows search" take 20 second to find it .

Do you know some tricks to optimize the search and make it more fast.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Windows search cheats; it *indexes* the data beforehand. In other words, it uses a dedicated search engine, and you are doing a brute-force search.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could he then index the files himself (supposing he is the one to place them in the first place, or run a one-time operation to do so?)

Comment: is there a way to use windows search with python ? or any similar ?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Sure; write a new search engine yourself. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I wasn't aware this would be a monumental task.  I thought perhaps there was some simplish way to cut down the time from 30 mins to 2 or something...

Comment: Yes, there is a service with a [Query API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872064(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: pywin32 cant do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

You are in the land of **[Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval)**, instead of searching from scratch every time - do what search engines do:

- [Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28search_engine%29) your data (pre-processing, done only once, or one in a while - this assumes the collection of documents is relatively stable - and changes very little comparing to the number of searches)
- Each time a query comes - search in the index to quickly find the answer.

This approach will allow you later on not only to return related documents - but will also allow you to rank them from most relevant to least relevant by using some already proven heuristics, such as the [tf-idf model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

There is an open-source project called **[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)**, which also has [python binding](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) that can help you with the implementations. Lucene is a mature widely used (and widely tested) Information-Retrieval library (used in eclipse search, for example)

---

**P.S.** If you find yourself interested in Information Retrieval further more, I recommend reading Manning's [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) - it will give you great understanding on the field - but it is really not mandatory for just applying your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows Search SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7388) + [Python ctypes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: I am a bit lost after searching for python ctypes using windows sdk , can you give me more info please .

Comment: cyptes allows calling functions in DLLs or shared libraries and Windows Search SDK providers such API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266517(v=vs.85).aspx. I have not personally used such integration myself and it is just a suggestion. I should have made it clear in my answer. My apology.

Comment: Gregory, if you eventually choose to do it this way, let me know how it turns out. :)